# Rewrite a url pattern to call out the same file (.htaccess)?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have dozens of different pages.
each page contains the two links in a similar pattern -

example:

`fruits.php` contains the links:

1. `/foo/fruits/abc`
2. `/foo/fruits/xyz`

`magnets.php` contains the links:

1. `/foo/magnets/abc`
2. `/foo/magnets/xyz`

Currently I'm using a different `.php` file to process each of these links, so my `.htaccess` looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/fruits/abc/?$ /web/fruits1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^foo/fruits/xyz/?$ /web/fruits2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^foo/magnets/abc/?$ /web/magnets1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^foo/magnets/xyz/?$ /web/magnets2.php [L]
```

instead, I want my `.hatccess` to call the same `process.php` file to handle all these links from the above two patterns, which are:

`/foo/(variable)/abc/` & `/foo/(variable)/xyz/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex matching to allow dynamic values in your URIs and have just **one single rule** for your requirements:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/\w+/\w+/?$ /web/process.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks but - 1. I don't want a dynamic value on on `/web/$1.php` - it should always be `/web/process.php` 2. I want a dynamic value here - `^foo/(value)/abc/?$` and here `^foo/(value)/xyz/?$`  (as I can't predict what will be the name that I add - magnets and fruits are just examples. 

so if I take your example, should it be something like:

`RewriteRule ^foo/\w+/(abc|xyz)/?$ /web/process.php [L]` (why did you add the NC flag btw?)

Comment: thanks, it works. should I use the NC flag or not? currently I'm only using L flag and it works fine

Comment: `NC` flag is got ignore case match it will match `/foo` or `/FOO` or `/Foo`. If you just want to match `/foo` just take out `NC` flag.